# Can I change my payment method after I made a payment in a restaurant with a credit card?

Tags: credit-card, payment

I have different credit cards and they give me different cashback rates depending on the category. For example, I get 5% cashback from dining with credit card A but only 1% from dining with credit card B.

I had a meal in a restaurant and paid with my credit card B. The next day I realised that I should have paid with my credit A as it gives me more cashback. In this case, is there anything that I can do to change the payment method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By this time they have scanned your card, received pre-authorization, and now after you added the tip, they may have sent the final transaction information. Even if it hasn't gone all the way to your account the process has started.

At this point the restaurant sees no benefit to making the change you are requesting. They would have to void the transaction, and then go through it again. If they are doing this request over the phone, they would be doing this as a card not present transaction.

If this was something that hadn't been shipped yet, the vendor could allow this by cancelling the first transaction and then resubmitting it. But you have received the product and consumed it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The merchant can. But they probably won't.

Likely you will have to go back to the restaurant and talk a manager into it.
It will likely be a pain to them for no benefit and may even cost them additional credit card processing fees.